# Why does my ADSL disconnect sometimes?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, adsl

I have a Linksys wireless ADSL modem. Sometimes I find that my Internet access is lost, so I'm forced to either:

1. Turn off the wireless application on my laptop and back on again
2. Turn off the modem, wait for five minutes (or more) and turn it back on again

On occasion however it will connect to the Internet again automatically.

Why does this keep happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't sign your name in your post; you are identified in the bottom-right corner of every post you make. Thanks!

Comment: Did you purchase your modem from a third party or from your ISP (or do you rent it)?

Comment: Please add a few details to your question (as @Daniel Mallott said). Also, have you spoken to your ISP about the problem? I can only tell you what happened with me - same symptoms. My provider decided to double every customer's available bandwidth, however my modem wasn't able to handle those speeds and would disconnect every time I fired up a high speed download.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is the modem portion and not the router or the wireless access point portion of the device?
The problem with ADSL modem/wireless routers are that they are four devices combined into one. They are a modem, router, switch and access point, all connected with internal wiring. This makes it a bit more difficult to troubleshoot exactly where the problem lies.

The first step is always check layer 1. Swap out cables, test with different NICs, different computers, different ports, different channels, etc.

Then you need to direct connect a computer using a cable and test ping to the primary DNS for a few hours. Look for packet loss, latency, jitter, etc. If you see problem, call your ISP and have them do a loop test (it is always best to call WHILE the problem is occurring and BEFORE you restart your equipment).

If you see a problem there, then you might try syncing at the NID. Take the modem out to the phone box, sync up there and run the same tests. Your ISP will want you to do this anyway as it rules out your building's wiring (a very common cause for issues).

If you still see problems there, the ISP will have to figure out what is going on (maybe your loop was extended, or you have some issues with margins that are being caused by a bad modem, voltage on the line, grounding, bridge taps, etc), but they'll be able to test for all that.

If you see no problems during those tests, then it is likely the router or access point. Connect two computers, when one goes out, see if the other still has access (in most cases, the wireless loses access, but the wired is fine). This indicates a problem with the wireless. If it is the other way around, the built in switch might be bad, or the router itself is having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I won't claim this is exactly your situation, but I can tell you a scenario when you can get disconnected.

Some ISPs consider that you are using the Internet if they see traffic coming from you. If there's no traffic (you don't have downloads in the background for example), your ISP pings your router. If your router is blocking ICMP and doesn't reply, ISP is disconnecting you and you have to reconnect. To deal with this, you should set up your router to reply to pings from outside (from your ISP at least).

Bear in mind this is a situation that assumes from the start that your hardware (adsl modem) is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

So often frequently disconnection issues it’s randomly occurring and you need to diagnose and troubleshoot it to determine is it from your ISP or Modem Or due to loss of the DSL signal.

In Linksys case you have useful functions to determine your issue by enable the Log to find out as following:

Administration TAB -> Reporting SUB-TAB -> under that you will find Log simply enable it.
  After you got disconnected too many times go to the same tab and view log to find out is it related to your ISP or other than that.

I’ll prefer to check with your ISP about the connection session life time, as this depends on the RADUIS system that used by your ISP.

I hope this will help you to solve your issue.